# Way to move the chess piece

Tags: problem-solving, chessboard

> Donald loves to play chess and often invents new pieces, making the
> game more interesting. Donald's chessboard is seen as a grid of $N$
> lines and $M$ columns. The rows are numbered from $1$ to $N$ from top
> to bottom, the columns are numbered from $1$ to $M$ to the right. The
> intersection of row $x$ column $y$ is called cell $(x;y)$.
>
> One day, he created a new piece by himself - piece $A$. The rule of
> this piece's movement is: if the piece is in cell $(x;y)$ then in the
> next step it can go to one of $4$ cell $(x,y+2),(x,y-2),(x-2,y)$ or
> $(x+2,y)$ provided that the cell is in the chessboard.
>
> He wondered, if we put piece $A$ in cell $(x_1,y_1)$, would it be
> possible to move the piece to cell $(x_2,y_2)$, and if so, at least
> how many steps would it take for the piece to get there

This is actually an exercise using my Python computer language, but I like to think of it mathematically. I'm trying to split the cases, the first case is that $x_1$ and $y_1$ are both even, so $x_2$ and $y_2$ are both odd, so there's no way to move to this cell. Same with other cases. But I'm quite confused because I don't think the answer is that simple, please tell me if the above thought is right or wrong, and if it is wrong, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Obviously , this piece can only reach even (or odd depending on the start position) row-numbers and also column-numbers. The parity of both coordinates keeps the same.

Comment: $~x_2,x_1~$ must have the same (odd/even) parity.  As a separate constraint, $~y_2,y_1~$ must have the same parity.  Each move preserves both the vertical and horizontal parity.

Comment: Following from @user2661923 's comment, given the starting position, delete the unvisitable rows and columns and I think you are just looking at the knight move problem on a smaller board.

Comment: @EthanBolker It is rather a piece that can move one to the left, right , up or down in a step. Such a piece does however not exists in the chess game. We could simulate it with a king that is however not able to move diagonal.

Comment: @Peter Right you are. You can delete the rows and columns as I said, but then the piece is what you have specified - a crippled king, or a crippled rook. Then the minimum number of steps to get from one spot to another is just the sum of the row and column distances on the modified board (so the taxicab metric distance). You should post an answer to the question.